# Can we update the status of Omni-Channel (Like available, Busy, Offline) through REST API call?

Tags: omnichannel

I have a requirement to update the Omni-Channel status from third party application. Like through third party, I can set the Omni-Channel status to Available, Busy or Offline.

Can anyone help on the same?

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible directly but you can create a rest api which will in turn fire the listener component on service console which can update the status using lightining Api for omnichannel.